# CRM 2013 : Data change in Active Directory synced by office 365 in user record is not triggering a OOB Workflow automatically

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I have an online CRM organization and also an OOB workflow written to execute on change of the primaryemailaddress field data in user record. But this workflow is not getting triggered when there is any change in the user data in Active Directory which getting synced up through office 365. Workflow is getting triggered when we are changing the data manually in the user record but not from the Active Directory changes.

Is there any limitions of workflow for this or what is the actual reason behind not triggering the workflow. If anybody has faced this issue before and just help me out in finding the root cause of it.

Thanks,
Samit

Comment: Smells like the sync is happening behind the scenes, with O365 info going straight to the database... If you enable Auditing on the field, is the change being recorded ? Also, I'd try to put up a plugin on User Update (doing something simple, just to keep track of the execution) to see if it triggers or not.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that means from O365 it directly updates in the DB. So in that case evenif we register a plugin then also it will not get triggered as it will not come under plugin execution pipeline